# Set Tab title as current date excel

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I want to set the tab title on my worksheet to the current date. I know if you want the cell of a worksheet to show the current date you just type `=Today()`. However if i set the tab title of the worksheet to this it literally comes up as =Today() and not the actual date.

Comment: The tab names don't support formulas like this. You can manually type the date in, or get a VBA function to change it (For example when the workbook is opened). However I would foresee a lot of trouble with continuously changing your tab name like that, for example broken references and VBA functions. It's best to pick a good static name instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no worksheet function to change the tab name. However, this simple macro will do the job.

```
Sub DateToTabName()
    ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy")
End Sub
```

You can invoke the macro by calling it from the*Developer* tab. From the *Macros* dialog box select *Options* to access a dialog which enables you to set a keyboard shortcut.